# Ads do not show in my application

Tags: android, ads

I don't know what I am missing, currently I have:

```
build gradle(project): maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }

build gradle(app):implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.1' 


xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
```

in the xml:

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/normBtnID"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/ratingBtnID"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/ratingBtnID" />
```

I have tried several codes, tried to put the adview programmatically and in the xml, for the current code I got the error adSize missing but it's there, when I add the ad programmatically it just shows a blank screen when launches the app

Comment: you need a class that is an Application class that stores your key.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the following to either the activity or the Application class...

```
MobileAds.initialize(this, "YOUR_ADMOB_APP_ID");
```

Read more here:

https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start

Answer (score 0):

I thin you must to use firebase firstly you can follow this link to do that and adding ads 
in correct way 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/quick-start

if you did that before 
I think the error is from your admob account 
go to Payments and confirm info  there 
ads will appear simply 
I hope that will be help you

Answer (score 0):

Could you try *android:layout_width="match_parent*" and *android:layout_height="70dp"* on Adview?

I faced same problem yesterday, hardcoded layout_height is work on my case.